# Assigning function to variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am assigning the filter function in a variable. Is it the right way of assignation?

It’s accounting “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier”.

```
var relevantState = $(cityMap).filter(function () {
    return this.state == selectedState;
});
```

Here is the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/rvurn2n7/

Comment: what is the citymap its a class or id?

Comment: use === to return a boolean

Comment: Note that you're assigning the *result* of the `filter()` function to the `relevantState` variable. This code is fine and shouldn't cause errors though. What is the content of the `cityMap` variable?

Comment: Here is the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/rvurn2n7/

Comment: I get no errors when I try your jsfiddle :S. What are the steps to get the errorr?

Comment: If I am copying this code in my webpage then its showing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error.

Comment: Do you have any other js code .. other than what is in your fiddle?

Comment: I don't know, What was the problem. For now I've replaced the jQuery's .filter() function with JavaScript's for loop method. After that it's working fine.

You can check the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/rvurn2n7/1/